# Connect-ExchangeOnline freezing when Importing cmdlet 'Test-ActiveToken'

Tags: powershell, xaml, office365

I have a XAML form using PowerShell. I'm looking to connect to Exchange Online to be able to manage Calendar / Mailbox permissions.

Below is a snippet of the scripts used to try bring the login box

**Main.ps1 script**

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework,WindowsBase,System.Windows.Forms,WindowsFormsIntegration

. $PSScriptRoot\Functions.ps1

Import-Module -Name 'ExchangeOnlineManagement'

$xaml = Join-Path $PSScriptRoot 'CalWindow.xaml'
$Launch_XAML = [XML](Get-Content $xaml)
$xamlReader_Launch = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $Launch_XAML
$Window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($xamlReader_Launch)

$btnConnect = $Window.FindName('btnConnect')

    [void]$Window.showDialog()
    [void]$window.Activate()
    $appContext = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext 
    [void][system.windows.forms.application]::Run($appContext)
```

**Functions.ps1 script**

```
function btnConnect {
    switch($btnConnect.Content) {
        "Connect" {
            Connect-ExchangeOnline
            $btnConnect.Content = "Disconnect"
            $lblStatus.Content = "Connected as "
        }
        "Disconnect" {
            Disconnect-ExchangeOnline -force
            $btnConnect.Content = "Connect"
            $lblStatus.Content = "Not Connected"
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever the button is clicked, the program appears to freeze. When adding `-verbose` flag to `Connect-ExchangeOnline` I get the below

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
The module allows access to all existing remote PowerShell (V1) cmdlets in addition to the 9 new, faster, and more reliable cmdlets.

|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|    Old Cmdlets                    |    New/Reliable/Faster Cmdlets       |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|    Get-CASMailbox                 |    Get-EXOCASMailbox                 |
|    Get-Mailbox                    |    Get-EXOMailbox                    |
|    Get-MailboxFolderPermission    |    Get-EXOMailboxFolderPermission    |
|    Get-MailboxFolderStatistics    |    Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistics    |
|    Get-MailboxPermission          |    Get-EXOMailboxPermission          |
|    Get-MailboxStatistics          |    Get-EXOMailboxStatistics          |
|    Get-MobileDeviceStatistics     |    Get-EXOMobileDeviceStatistics     |
|    Get-Recipient                  |    Get-EXORecipient                  |
|    Get-RecipientPermission        |    Get-EXORecipientPermission        |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|

To get additional information, run: Get-Help Connect-ExchangeOnline or check https://aka.ms/exops-docs

Send your product improvement suggestions and feedback to exocmdletpreview@service.microsoft.com. For issues related to the module, contact Microsoft support. Don't use the feedback alias for problems or support issues.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

VERBOSE: ExchangeEnvironment : O365Default
VERBOSE: ConnectionUri :
VERBOSE: AzureADAuthorizationEndpointUri :
VERBOSE: DelegatedOrganization :
VERBOSE: Prefix :
VERBOSE: FormatTypeName :*
VERBOSE: CommandName :*
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Add-EXOClientTelemetryWrapper'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'New-EXOClientTelemetryFilepath'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Push-EXOTelemetryRecord'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Clear-ActiveToken'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'New-ExoPSSession'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Test-ActiveToken'.
```

Have I missed something to get this to work with a form, Sometimes when I close the window it will then bring the login box, but this is unreliable. I get the same issue when trying to define credentials with `-Credential $creds` flag

If I try to connect when the script loads, it appears to work fine, but I need it to work with different account logins

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this problem as well. I think I have narrowed it down to what is causing it and a few solutions.

It seems to be related to 2.0.4 and 2.0.5 versions of the ExchangeOnlineManagement module and the placement of the Connect-ExchangeOnline cmdlet in the script, and Windows PowerShell 5.1. I have found that using 2.0.3 or earlier does not have this problem. With 2.0.4 and 2.0.5, here is some simple code to test/confirm the problem:

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$FormMain = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
Connect-ExchangeOnline

The problem is the "New-Object" cmdlet. If you call this before the Connect-ExchangeOnline cmdlet, the problem will happen (in 2.0.4 and 2.0.5). If you call Connect-ExchangeOnline before any and all Add-Type cmdlets, then it will work.

If you use PowerShell 7.x, then it also works.

So my suggestions are to use 2.0.3 (but then you use any new benefits of newer module releases) or re-order your code to make sure you authenticate first and then use the Add-Type cmdlets. Or switch to PowerShell 7.x.

Taken from: https://www.sapien.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=15297